# How to copy spaces from one string to another in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need a way to copy all of the positions of the spaces of one string to another string that has no spaces.

For example:

```
string1 = "This is a piece of text"
string2 = "ESTDTDLATPNPZQEPIE"

output = "ESTD TD L ATPNP ZQ EPIE"
```

Answer (score 3):

Insert characters as appropriate into a placeholder list and concatenate it after using `str.join`.

```
it = iter(string2)
output = ''.join(
    [next(it) if not c.isspace() else ' ' for c in string1]  
)
```

```
print(output)
'ESTD TD L ATPNP ZQ EPIE'
```

This is efficient as it avoids repeated string concatenation.

Comment: why `.isspace()`? very clever though :)

Comment: @JoeIddon cleaner than `c == ' '` imo, and thank you. I like your generator solution, it was the first thing I came up with myself.

Comment: But in general, `==` is more extensible. Oh also, isn't the list-comp unnecessary as you can just use a generator if passing into`str.join`.

Comment: @JoeIddon Ah, that's a common gotcha with `str.join`. It is _faster_ to pass a list than a generator, because str.join will anyway make a second pass over it to create the list in memory. There is a source somewhere, I can find it.

Comment: @JoeIddon You may peruse this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/4909087) by Raymond Hettinger.

Comment: Very interesting! But what about the cases where you aren't using a comprehension as in my answer... Would it be faster there to pass into `list()` first.

Comment: Also, when Raymond says: "If you give it one, it can start its work immediately. If you give it a genexp instead, it cannot start work until it builds-up a new list", if you have to create the list yourself, then I get that this would save time for the `str.join` call, but you have lost all the time you saved by creating a list (over a generator). I do agree that it is faster though now I have checked; is it simply the overhead of closing a generator?

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the indexes and characters in `string1` using `enumerate()`.

On each iteration, if the character is a space, add a space to the output string (note that this is inefficient as you are creating a new object as strings are immutable), otherwise add the character in `string2` at that index to the output string.

So that code would look like:

```
output = ''
si = 0
for i, c in enumerate(string1):
    if c == ' ':
         si += 1
         output += ' '
    else:
         output += string2[i - si]
```

However, it would be more efficient to use a very similar method, but with a generator and then `str.join`. This removes the slow concatenations to the output string:

```
def chars(s1, s2):
    si = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(s1):
        if c == ' ':
            si += 1
            yield ' '
        else:
            yield s2[i - si]
output = ''.join(char(string1, string2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try insert method :

```
string1 = "This is a piece of text"
string2 = "ESTDTDLATPNPZQEPIE"


string3=list(string2)

for j,i in enumerate(string1):
    if i==' ':
        string3.insert(j,' ')
print("".join(string3))
```

outout:

```
ESTD TD L ATPNP ZQ EPIE
```